# Is there any way to access variables of one JavaScript file into another?

Tags: javascript, html

I am building a movie search website in which when the user clicks on the movie card it redirects it to another page named "movie.html" which has info about the movie.

but when I am at the "movie.html" page I need the name of the movie to fetch data from OMDB API to apply changes dynamically in the "movie.html" page.

for that, I need access to variables from the original script file in the script file of "movie.html".

Comment: You should add [minimal reproducible code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
Please edit your question to show what research you've done and any attempts you've made to solve the problem yourself

Comment: Pass the movie id in the url and call your API with that id on the next page.

Comment: Share variables with fetching json file at each .html files.

Answer (score 0):

A variable in the global scope can be accessed from all javascript files.
Your first js file

```
var globalVariable={
       movie_id: 1
    };
```

And your second js file

```
alert(globalVariable.movie_id);
```

And in html page add-

Comment: I think OP is really asking how to pass a value from one page to another!